# Wordpress Multisite Internal Links

Tags: wordpress, nginx, hyperlink, domain-mapping

I am trying to make a Wordpress Multisite network with domain mapping, and I am using nginx as the webserver.

The master blog URL is www.xenon-corporation.com, that works fine.

I can create subdomains just fine, such as teste.xenon-corporation.com.
I can even map the domains such as www.vinerz.net.

But the internal links on the page still point to the old subdomain vinerz.xenon-corporation.com and not the new domain www.vinerz.net.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP Multisite stores domain names all over the database...

table wp_options*: option_name 'siteurl' and 'home'

table wp_site: each row has domain and path columns

table wp_sitemeta: meta_key 'siteurl'

table wp_blogs: each row has domain and path columns

* and there is a wp_#_options table for each site you have in your network...